# Insert Dictionary into MongoDB with c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, dictionary, insert

I am in a situation where I can't predict which fields my MongoDB document is going to have. So I can no longer create an object with an `_id` field of type `BsonID`. 
I find it very convenient to create a Dictionary (HashTable) and add my DateTime and String objects inside, as many times as I need it.

I then try to insert the resulting Dictionary object into MongoDb, but default serialization fails.

Here's my object of Type HashTable (like a Dictionary, but with varied types inside):

```
{ "_id":"",
"metadata1":"asaad",
"metadata2":[],
"metadata3":ISODate("somedatehere")}
```

And the error from the driver I get is:

> Serializer DictionarySerializer expected serialization options of type DictionarySerializationOptions, not DocumentSerializationOptions

I googled it, but couldn't find anything useful. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The driver needs to be able to find the _id field. You could create a C# class that has just two properties: Id and Values.

```
public class HashTableDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    [BsonExtraElements]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }

}
```

Note that we have to use Dictionary<string, object> instead of Hashtable.

You could then use code like the following to insert a document:

```
var document = new HashTableDocument
{
    Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(),
    Values = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "metadata1", "asaad" },
        { "metadata2", new object[0] },
        { "metadata3", DateTime.UtcNow }
    }
};
collection.Insert(document);
```

We can use the MongoDB shell to confirm that the inserted document has the desired form:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("518abdd4e447ad1f78f74fb1"),
        "metadata1" : "asaad",
        "metadata2" : [ ],
        "metadata3" : ISODate("2013-05-08T21:04:20.895Z")
}
>
```

Comment: @RobertStam This provides solution for "dynamic" fields. Two questioins: **1)** in a bakery app, users prefer to keep their own convention of writing `brand A, sugar, 2 (implies spoon), 300 (implies temperature), 20 (implies minutes)`. Each doesn't have a key. **2)** As I do more reading, [mapping class](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/) also points out I have to use `IDictionary`, Fine. But it states it won't preserve the order. Any way to preserve order?